# Tableau Q: Calculating Average from Duplicate Rows

Tags: sql-server, database, data-visualization, tableau-api, data-warehouse

I have this data warehouse with table structure like this. I want to create visualization using tableau for average customer points per year.

```
CustomerID  ,Order      ,CustomerPoints ,OrderYear
A123        ,Table      ,450        ,2014
A123        ,Chair      ,450        ,2014
B236        ,Mouse      ,500        ,2014
B236        ,Keyboard   ,500        ,2014
B236        ,Monitor    ,500        ,2014
C135        ,Cabinet    ,600        ,2014
D246        ,Lamp       ,400        ,2014
```

If I do average straight away it will count 7 rows instead of 4 distinct row.

This is how it should be calculated

`CustomerID  ,CustomerPoints ,OrderYear
    A123    ,450        ,2014
    B236    ,500        ,2014
    C135    ,600        ,2014
    D246    ,400        ,2014`


`OrderYear, AverageCustomerPoints
2014, 487.5`

`CustomerPoints from each of customerID/count customerID (4 people)`

I tried count distinct per customer ID and using `{Fixed ([CustomerID]) : Average([CustomerPoints])}` but the result is different when I tried to do it manually using different table.

Is there any way to do this strictly using tableau calculation/feature for this?

Comment: can you share the desired output sample?

Comment: I added it on body text. Thank you.

Comment: create a view using this data and use that view in your tableau reporting. While creating view you can easily solve this by using normal Aggregate function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helped by someone
`AVG({Fixed ([CustomerID]) : AVG([CustomerPoints])})`

Answer (score 0):

You can write the query for view like this :

```
SELECT CustomerID, OrderYear, AVG(CustomerPoints) AS (CustomerPoints) 
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY CustomerID, OrderYear
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I wonder if I can do the calculation in tableau instead creating new view/table.